# How to prefer no choice instead of bad choice with sklearn decision tree

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-trees

I'm using sklearn decision trees to classify documents in two possible types "type1" and "type2".

I've isolated few features that seem pertinent and tried to combine them manually to evaluate the result of a model.
When classifying the documents manually i use the following outcomes:

- type 1
- type 2
- unknown

Then I give the same features to a decision tree. The results are worse in that case because it always tries to classify documents in one of the categories "type1" or "type2" but is unable to classify documents in "unknown"

Is it possible to configure a sklearn decision tree in a way that in case of high uncertainty the document won't be classified instead of selecting a category that is likely to be wrong?

Comment: How about teaching it to recognise type3=unknown? You might probably need to annotate some samples manually.

Comment: actually my dataset is labeled with "type1" & "type2" but in my environment we prefer to display no result instead of bad results. Of course the final goal is to have a maximum of correct "type1" & "type2". Just i wonder if a "defensive" strategy exists to avoid errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

You can train your classifier as usual and threshold on the prediction probability.

## Scikit-learn

You won't get that out of the box, but you can use this simple class to do just that!

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from numpy import argmax, max

class MyClassifier(DecisionTreeClassifier):

    unknown_class = 'unknown'

    def __init__(self, no_class_threshold=0.75, **kwargs):
        self.no_class_threshold = no_class_threshold
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def predict(self, X):
        preds = self.predict_proba(X)
        y_pred = [self.classes_[i] if v > self.no_class_threshold else self.unknown_class
                  for i, v in zip(argmax(preds, axis=1), max(preds, axis=1))]
        return y_pred
```

Just use this class as you were using the `DecisionTreeClassifier` before. You can pass all the parameters from `DecisionTreeClassifier` plus an extra one: `no_class_threshold`.

The `no_class_threshold` works in the following way:

```
IF
    prediction_probability > no_class_threshold
THEN
    output predicted class
ELSE
    output 'unknown'
```

## Changing classifier

You might not want to stay with the `DecisionsTreeClassfier`, and instead, you might want to experiment with other classifiers. You can do this by inheriting from another Scikit-learn class. Simple as that!

For example:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC

class MyClassifier(SVC):
    [...]
```

## Choosing the `no_class_threshold`

You can:

- Choose it manually, to a degree that you feel confident
- Use hyper-parameter tuning to learn it, if you have data points labelled as **'unknown'**.

## Example

Here is a script you can run to test all the above.

```
from numpy import argmax, max
from sklearn.svm import SVC


class MyClassifier(SVC):
    unknown_class = 'unknown'

    def __init__(self, no_class_threshold=0.75, **kwargs):
        self.no_class_threshold = no_class_threshold
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def predict(self, X):
        preds = self.predict_proba(X)
        y_pred = [self.classes_[i] if v > self.no_class_threshold else self.unknown_class
                  for i, v in zip(argmax(preds, axis=1), max(preds, axis=1))]
        return y_pred


if __name__ == '__main__':
    X = [[1, 1, 1],
         [1, 0, 1],
         [0, 0, 0],
         [0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 1]]
    y = ['class1', 'class1', 'class0', 'class0', 'class0']

    clf = MyClassifier(no_class_threshold=0.55, probability=True, C=1)

    clf.fit(X, y)

    X2 = [[1, 1, 0],
          [0, 1, 1],
          [0, 0, 1]]
    pred = clf.predict(X2)
    print(pred)
```

Comment: Thx for your answer Bruno, it's working as expected

Comment: @Bertrand I am glad to hear. Out of curiosity, which classifier did you end up using? Did you stay with a **Decision Tree**?

Comment: i've tested both DecisionTree & SVC. The results look quite similar for now. Just to clarify, your comment says that DecisionTree classifier only returns probabilites 0 & 1. However in my test it's not the case, maybe it could updated in your answer.

Comment: @Bertrand thanks for the comment, I updated it. Was probably just my example ;)